# What is default rest api time out in spring boot 2.2

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, rest

What is default api time out in spring boot 2.2 and how i can change this. is any property key which is used to changes time out.
i want to set time out after 10 sec.

Comment: @Transactional annotation takes a timeout parameter where you can specify timeout in seconds for a specific method in the RestController

Answer (score 2):

Via @Transactional annotation you can specify a timeout in seconds for a specific method in the @RestController.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Transactional(timeout = 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setting server.connection-timeout=10000 in your application.properties or application.yml.

server.connection-timeout - Time in milliseconds that connectors will wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection. When not set, the connector's container-specific default will be used. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout.

Comment: I have already added server.tomcat.connection-timeout=30s in application, but time out is not working

Comment: Are you running on tomcat or on spring boot own servlet container? I suppose that mentioned upper settings works only for spring boot own servlet container

Comment: You could also see this (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-tomcat) article. It could be helpful, but they are also use same settings, however they set value as string - 5s for five seconds